# VBA - Passing argument to function in loop

Tags: vba, arguments

Here is some code, that I'm working with:

```
Function func(x As Double) As Double
func = (x * x) - 5
End Function

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim a, b, dok, fa, fb, f0, x0 As Double

a = Val(TextBox1.Text)
b = Val(TextBox2.Text)
dok = Val(TextBox3.Text)

If Not IsNumeric(a) Or Not IsNumeric(b) Or Not IsNumeric(dok) Then
    MsgBox ("Incorrect data!")
    Else
        fa = func(Val(a))
        fb = func(Val(b))
        If (fa * fb) > 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Function does not meet requirements!")
        Else
            Do While Abs(Val(a) - Val(b)) > Val(dok)
            x0 = ((Val(a) + Val(b)) / 2)
            f0 = func(Val(x0))
            If Abs(Val(f0)) < Val(dok) Then
                MsgBox ("OK!")
                TextBox4.Text = x0
                Exit Do
            End If
            If (fa * f0) < 0 Then
                b = x0
                Else
                    a = x0
                    f0 = fa
            End If
            Loop
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Input data is a = 0 and b = 10, dok = 2.

Everything is OK, until in second step of Do-While loop, variable x0 gets 2,5 value (which is OK) and this value is passed to function here:

```
f0 = func(Val(x0))
```

Function func gets argument 2 instead of 2,5. Why so? I've tried to pass by hand 2,5 argument to function and it works. Also I've tried to calculate 2,5 with similar way and pass it and it works too.

```
Dim test, test2 As Double
test = func(2.5)
MsgBox "Result: " & test
test2 = Abs((0 - 5) / 2)
MsgBox "ABS result: " & test2
test = func(test2)
MsgBox "Second result to: " & test
```

Comment: Some code is missing - it doesn’t make sense

Comment: Show us the lines where you define the datatypes of `x0`, `f0`, `fa` etc. Also, do you notice that `fa` is always 0 throughout the code you provided? Which means the If `(fa*f0) < 0` case is never relevant.

Comment: `Option Explicit`!

Comment: I've put all code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at how you've expressed `2.5` as `2,5` in your question, this smells like a localisation issue. Specifically, from the [MDSN page on the `Val` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/val-function):

> The Val function recognizes only the period ( . ) as a valid decimal separator. When different decimal separators are used, as in international applications, use CDbl instead to convert a string to a number.

Luckily, in this code, the offending `Val` is unnecessary: `x0` is already a Double, so there is no need to call `Val` on it. Thus we can change that line to

`f0 = func(x0)`

and probably the next line to

`If Abs(f0) < dok Then`

and it should all work fine.

Additionally, to make it safe for decimal inputs, `Val` should be removed from the lines assigning `fa` and `fb`, and `CDbl` should be used instead of `Val` for the TextBox inputs.